# CHROME showing http response as cancelled

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api

Using Chrome developer tools.I am getting a cancelled status on a request to a WEB API resource.(network tab)

Server : WEB API 2.1
Client: Angular $http request

The initial message referred to a CORS violation as the cause. I enabled CORS on the server.

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //Going camel case in Web API http://frankapi.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/going-camelcase-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api/
        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // cors support
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute( "http://localhost:9168/", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();
    }
}
```

After CORS was implemented, I am still getting cancelled a response message on the API calls, however, when drilling into the message, the data is being returned from the server.

I checked Fiddler and the request header is passing the origin etc correctly, however I am still getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4416/api/LookupTrades. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9168' is therefore not allowed access.
```

There seems to be loads of posts about the cancelled status in chrome, all with different causes. Not sure what to do next. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

install a Nuget package `"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" (version="5.1.0")

Add following line in your WebApiConfig.cs file

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

you can also set this property in your js file before ajax call

```
$.support.cors = true;
```